# read POST request parameter from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, post

I found other similar questions but I couldn't figure it out why I can't read POST request parameters (I have a form) from servlet (GET parameters are OK). So, with firebug I can see the values of the parameters introduced in the form but the below system.out.println shows them null.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        IPentahoSession userSession = PentahoSessionHolder.getSession();
        String username = userSession.getName().toString();
        openSql();
        response.setContentType(
                "text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        pw.println(
                "<html>");
        pw.println(
                "<head><title>Hello Pentaho</title></title>");
        pw.println(
                "<body>");
        pw.println(
                "<h1>Hello " + username + " Pentaho </h1>");

        pw.println(
                "<form method=\"post\" action=\"HelloPentaho\" >"
                + "Nume: <input type=\"varchar\" name=\"param1\" value=\"\"> <br>"
                + "Nume raport original: <input type=\"varchar\" name=\"param2\" value=\"\"> <br>"
                + "Cale raport original: <input type=\"text\" name=\"param3\" value=\"\"> <br>"
                + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Trimite date in baza\">"
                + "</form> ");

        pw.println(
                "<h1> The selected parameters are: " + request.getParameter("param1") + " " + request.getParameter("param2") + " " + request.getParameter("param3") + "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<br /></h1>");
        pw.println(
                "</body></html>");

        String insert = "INSERT INTO PREFERINTE_UTILIZATOR (nume,nume_rap_org,cale_rap_org) values (?,?,?);";
        PreparedStatement pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        pstmnt.setString(1, request.getParameter("param1"));
        pstmnt.setString(2, request.getParameter("param2"));
        pstmnt.setString(3, request.getParameter("param3"));
        pstmnt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HelloPentaho.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HelloPentaho.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
```

Comment: can you be more descriptive about the error you're getting.

Comment: after I press the form submit button, the pw.println should bring the parameters introduced in the form but all it brings is null for all of them. In the firebug, I can see the values of the parameters sent with post but I don't see them in the webpage.

Comment: I've had similar situations in the past. Cross check the input names on your form once and see if you're requesting for the same parameters on your servlet too.

Comment: I double checked it. No luck

Comment: anyone with an answer?

Comment: for once, try printing the parameters in the doPost function instead of passing the request and response objects to the doGet function and see what gets printed.

Comment: I printed the parameters in the doPost but still the same result.I also made the modification int the above question.

Comment: This should work if you're doing everything alright. Can you post the html here?

Comment: input type="varchar" ? In any case this just works, unless the above code is not the real code and the form is actually a multipart form. Then you indeed cannot get the POST parameters this way.

Comment: @Gimby I don't upload any file so, from what I've read, it's not a multipart form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or modify your doPost code to print the values in the console and see what gets printed. try this:

```
Enumeration enParams = request.getParameterNames(); 
while(enParams.hasMoreElements()){
 String paramName = (String)enParams.nextElement();
 System.out.println("Attribute Name - "+paramName+", Value - "+request.getParameter(paramName));
}
```

Comment: I tried the enumeration but I don't have any prints in the console or in the web page (I also tried a pw.println). The only information that gets printed is System.out.println(enParams) with the following: org.springframework.security.ui.savedrequest.Enumerator@22c837c1

Comment: printing out enParams would obviously print out an Enumerator object. Really strange. The most common errors in general are: incorrect mapping of servlet from jsp or bad param names in the servlet.

Comment: it seems that there is a problem with pentaho BI. Thanks Ritikesh for your replies